# Problems with Photoshop CS5 on Wine 1.3: C++ Library Runtime Error

Tags: wine, c++, photoshop, winetricks

When I try running Photoshop CS3 after installing it following [this tutorial](http://maketecheasier.com/install-photoshop-cs5-in-ubuntu-maverick/2010/11/02), I got

[image]

Also I noticed that http://pastie.org/1877592

> `jiewmeng@JM:/works/tmp/adobe$
>   winetricks msxml6 gdiplus gecko
>   vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 msxml3 atmlib
>   ... vcrun2005 install completed, but
>   installed file
>   /home/jiewmeng/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/winsxs/x86_Microsoft.VC80.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.5592_x-ww_e87e0bcd/mfc80.dll not found`

I am thinking thats a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Winetricks will solve that for you.

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Then search winetricks for mfc80:

```
winetricks dlls list | grep mfc80
```

It will output something like:

```
vcrun2005                Visual C++ 2005 libraries (mfc80,msvcp80,msvcr80) (Microsoft, 2011) [downloadable]
```

Just install the winetricks "package" it wants you to install with:

```
winetricks <package>
```

which in this case, would be:

```
winetricks vcrun2005
```

Comment: I got something like `vcrun2005 already installed, skipping` but I notice that the out put of `winetricks dlls list | grep mfc80` has mfc80 in red

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from here: http://www.dll-files.com/ - and place it in the location where it's required (I'm guessing ~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows unless you have a custom directory).